# Turning an Equation from Polar Form to Rectangular Form

Tags: trigonometry

Recently, I was working on a problem where I had to turn a polar equation into a rectangular one. The equation in question was
$$ r=\tan \phi $$ When I simplified it into rectangular form, I reached
$$y=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ by replacing each part of the polar equation with rectangular variables. Although I know the equation itself is right, I believe that it has to be written in a different form for it to be considered correct. What other forms can this equation be written in?

Comment: "it has to be written in a different form for it to be considered correct": what do you mean ? What are your after ?

Answer (score 1):

We would like to consider the curve $$\sqrt{y^2+x^2} =\frac yx$$ What you’ve done is you’ve squared both sides to isolate $y$, but often times squaring loses the identity of an equation. The correct way would be to get to $$y=\pm\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$ Now, notice, in the original equation the LHS is always positive, and so $\frac yx$ must be too. This is accomplished when $x,y$ have the same sign. Hence, the required function will be $$y=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, & x\gt 0 \\ \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, & x\lt 0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Beware that the polar modulus is a positive number so that the equation only has solutions for $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2)$ plus multiples of $\pi$, i.e. the first and third quadrants, where $x$ and $y$ take the same sign.

Then

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac yx$$ gives the solution

$$y=\text{sgn}(x)\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},$$ for $x\in(-1,1)$.

---

If you admit negative moduli, then the equation is equivalent to

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\left|\frac yx\right|,$$

with the solutions

$$y=\pm\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$